# Error in Visual Studio 2015 When trying to "Get Latest Version (Recursive)"

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting this weird error in visual studio 2015 when I try to get the latest of the solution... The error I'm getting is in a Visual Studio 2015; an error popup that says "The dbType NVarChar is invalid for this constructor." I've been trying to look this up for hours with no luck...

[image: When Getting the latest version (recursive) this is the error that's popping up]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Reinstall your VS2015

Comment: Same error. Getting latest sources from Source Control Explorer still works for me

Comment: Is this error related just to Visual Studio Online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same error, I got it working with the following steps:

1. Commit the pending changes
2. Resolved any conflicts found & commit the pending changes again
3. Get Latest Version (Recursive)

Comment: Thanks for the tip I tried yours first as it was the least complex, I really didn't want to check in until I had a stable version of the code. So perhaps the lack of checking in caused some issues. weird error all good now.

Comment: You don't need to actually commit your changes - I have clicked "Check in", merged changes, but after that in place of making actual check-in, I made "Get latest version" and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

try undo pending changes in your solution from the source control panel

**Beware:** you will lose the changes you mades before